# Hibernate OGM Mongodb projection

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm using Hibernate OGM Mongodb and I need to do some projections against my queries, do someone already done that and can help me?

I've already tried to use the JP-QL queries, but none of my attempts have succeeded.

Here is the query that I tried:

```
// using JP-QL
select 'code' from example a where a.code = 33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct JP-QL

```
select a.code from example a where a.code = 33
```

You can find multiple examples [in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/#ogm-jpql-query).

I'm assuming the entity mapping is something like this:

```
@Entity(name = "example")
class Example {

  Integer code;

}
```

If you didn't specify the name of the entity, the default name is `Example`:

```
select a.code from Example a where a.code = 33
```